# How to view request and response in Gatling report

Tags: scala, gatling

I running a Gatling test with maven, It has high charts, i want to view the request and response data in that report page. Request and response is very useful to find the defects.

Answer (score -1):

What you want is not possible as of current versions.

But note that in JMeter 3.0, you can :

- have a HTML dynamic report generated http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html
- Real-time graphed results when using a 3rd party backend server for metrics, see http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html

But I am not sure this answers your request.